# Why does setBitmap not seem to work in ICS?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am drawing to a canvas and simply trying to save the canvas to a JPEG. I have tested this on some devices and noticed that it does not seem to work on ICS and gives me an UnsupportedOperationException error when I try the following code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);

// Drawing to canvas here

OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/test.jpg");
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
stream.close();
```

This is all done in the onDraw method and the error is on the canvas.setBitmap(bitmap).

This works fine on my Droid X(2.3) and Tab 10.1(3.1), but fails on my Galaxy Nexus(4.0) and my Tab 10.1 when running ICS. I may just be over looking something really simple. I have been working on this most of the night and not making any progress. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:
I turned off "Force GPU rendering" and now it seems to work. There has to be a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling "Force GPU rendering" in settings has fixed the problem, even though there maybe a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain that the problem is that [strict mode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) is enabled. Since the `bitmap.compress` method does file I/O, strict mode is going to be unhappy about the fact that you're doing such an operation on the main thread. Try doing the compression step on a background thread, using an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), for example. Or, if you don't care about potentially introducing unresponsive moments in your UI, just turn of strict mode.

Comment: Well, I have strict mode disabled in my settings. I have tried to do this from an AsyncTask, but I'm guessing since it has to redraw the canvas to save it to a bitmap, I am getting the leaked window error.